# Unable to authenticate Google Calendar API v3 programmatically?

Tags: c#, oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Perhaps I am the only one that thinks Google's API documentation is awful but I've spent more time on this simple task than I wanted.

Currently my project is using a GDATA implementation to connect with the Google Calendar API v2. I followed this guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565032/Google-Calendar-Integration-in-ASP-NET-Create-ed

But I noticed that Google is deprecating version 2 of their API this fall. I am trying to figure out how I can connect to their version 3 API which appears to be using OAuth2.

After reading their documentation and searching the internet >:( - The problem I keep running into is EVERY sample, tutorial or youtube video I've come across that shows how to implement this involve the Google consent screen where the user clicks "Accept".

I've tried doing the following but honestly not sure if it's even the right direction?

```
    // Register the authenticator. The Client ID and secret have to be copied from the API Access
    // tab on the Google APIs Console.
    var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
    provider.ClientIdentifier = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
    provider.ClientSecret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET";

    // Create the service. This will automatically call the previously registered authenticator.
    var service = new CalendarService();
```

My application doesn't need the user's account/consent (OAuth), I need to connect like I am currently in my code-behind.

So the question is how do I "upgrade" my current implementation to v3? Do I use OAuth, Service Account? I've found plenty of examples showing the v3 usages for how to retrieve events and insert them... but they all authenticate with a user consent screen on the front end.

Here is my current GData implementation...

```
public class GoogleGateway : IGoogleGateway
    {
        private readonly IRepository<UserSetting> _settingsRepository;
        private Service _googleService;
        private CalendarService _googleCalendar;
        private Uri _calendarUri;

        public GoogleGateway(IRepository<UserSetting> settingsRepository)
        {
            _settingsRepository = settingsRepository;
        }

        public IEnumerable<EventEntry> GetAllEvents(DateTime? startDate)
        {
            if (!Connect()) return new List<EventEntry>();

            // Create the query object:
            EventQuery query = new EventQuery();
            query.Uri = _calendarUri;
            if (startDate != null)
                query.StartTime = startDate.Value;

            // Tell the service to query:
            EventFeed calFeed = _googleCalendar.Query(query);
            return calFeed.Entries.Cast<EventEntry>();
        }

        public bool Connect()
        {
            var calSettings = _settingsRepository.Get().Where(x => x.Setting == "Calendar");

            if (calSettings.Any())
            {
                var username = calSettings.First(x => x.Meta == "GoogleUsername").Value;
                var password = calSettings.First(x => x.Meta == "GooglePassword").Value;
                var calendarUri = new Uri(calSettings.First(x => x.Meta == "CalendarFeed").Value);
                var applicationName = calSettings.First(x => x.Meta == "ApplicationName").Value;

                _calendarUri = calendarUri;

                //FeedQuery feedQuery = new FeedQuery();

                _googleService = new Service("cl", applicationName);
                _googleCalendar = new CalendarService(applicationName);

                // Set your credentials:
                _googleService.setUserCredentials(username, password);
                _googleCalendar.setUserCredentials(username, password);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void AddEvent(string title, string contents, string location, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            if (!Connect()) return;

            EventEntry.EVENT_CATEGORY = new AtomCategory("Appointments");
            EventEntry entry = new EventEntry
            {
                Title = { Text = title },
                Content = { Content = contents },
            };

            // Set the title and content of the entry.

            // Set a location for the event.
            Where eventLocation = new Where();
            eventLocation.ValueString = location;
            entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation);

            When eventTime = new When(startTime, endTime);
            entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

            Uri postUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

            // Send the request and receive the response:
            AtomEntry insertedEntry = _googleCalendar.Insert(postUri, entry);
        }

        public void DeleteEvent(string eventId)
        {
            if (!Connect()) return;

            var events = GetAllEvents(null);

            var appointment = events.First(x => x.EventId == eventId);
            _googleService.Delete(appointment);
        }
    }
```

I'm growing desperate at this point, any help would be very appreciated. Include your twitter handle in your answer and I'll buy you a coffee!

**UPDATED**
I currently have the following, but I is still not authenticating... :(

```
    static CalendarService BuildService()
    {
        String serviceAccountEmail = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx-31xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

        var certPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/xxxxxxxxxxxx.p12");
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential, <<<<<< DOES NOT RESOLVE!
            ApplicationName = "MyApplication",
        });

        var test = service.Calendars.Get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com");

        return service;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing credentials in plaintext. In Oauth2 the users won't give you their credentials (thus access to everything) but instead they enable your app to access the data of a specific type / scope.

It's not clear from your description whether you only ever access one calendar fully in your control or you have multiple users. In the first case the answer would be use service account (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). In the second case if you are a calendar app with many users, you will need to go down the user consent road and you should read on :)

For offline access you can specify that the access_type should be offline when retrieving the credentials for the first time. Together with the access token you'll also get a refresh token, which you can use to re-authenticate at any later time without any more user clicks (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh). However, at least one consent screen it is.

Comment: I am just trying to access it from my code behind, no UI. Does the library has a class or method for working with service accounts? How do I authenticate using a service account, any example you can provide? All I see is OAuth ones.

Comment: The service account still uses Oauth but you don't need to do any user consent as the service account will act on its own behalf. You can share the calendar you want to access with this service account or you can even use the primary calendar of the service account. There is a nice drive documentation with some code in multiple languages https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts It works the same way for calendar.

Comment: Just so I understand this correctly, I need to download and store a certificate on the server and use the API key.